# Change comment font color in MySQL Workbench query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Is it possible to change the font color from a light grey to something more vibrant

[image]

```
    # GET TODAY'S EVENTS ONLY <- this is the font I want to change
    where event_date = CURDATE();
```

I am currently using MySQL Workbench version 6.0.9.11421 on Windows 7 OS

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you want to change in fact is the colors for syntax highlighting. These colors are stored in an xml file and there's currently no GUI to change them. But you can edit the xml file directly (restart MySQL Workbench to pick up any change). Look for the file code_editor.xml in your MySQL Workbench installation directory.

There are sections for each supported MySQL server like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<languages>
  <language name="SCLEX_MYSQL">
    <!-- This is the base language setting. It's usually not directly used, but provides values shared by
         more specialized MySQL versions. -->

    <!-- Lexer properties -->
    <property name="fold" value="1" />
    <property name="fold.compact" value="0" />
    <property name="fold.comment" value="1" />
    ...
    <style id="1" fore-color="#A0A0A0" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENT -->
    <style id="2" fore-color="#A0A0A0" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENTLINE -->
    ...
  </language>
  ...
</languages>
```

There are a number style tags each specifying a forground and background color (and styling like bold, italic) for each type of token. This is where you can adjust the colors to whatever you like. Make a copy of the original file in case you need to restore it.

Comment: Any idea where this is on OSX? I don't see it.

Comment: The file is in the app bundle: /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/data.