# Change syntax highlight colors in MySQLWorkbench

Tags: mysql, syntax-highlighting

Does anyone know of a way to change the syntax highlight colors in MySQLWorkbench on OSX? The gray color for comments is really hard for me to read. I did see [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26401408/change-comment-font-color-in-mysql-workbench-query), but I suspect this is for Windows and I don't see that file anywhere in OSX.

Comment: Not sure about that one, but we have some nice Dark Theme userscripts for browsers (no fried out eyes after looking at 300 questions a day like we do) ... http://i.imgur.com/OowkNev.jpg

Comment: Bill #2 here by rank on the tag: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-have-dark-theme-in-MySQL-Workbench ... on another note, to me at least it is worth choosing another tool. But it is the one I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer - the code_editor.xml file is in the resources/data folder of the application contents.

Answer (score 5):

you have to edit the code_editor. xml file and change the  following style tags

```
<style id="1" fore-color="#A0A0A0" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENT -->
<style id="2" fore-color="#A0A0A0" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENTLINE -->
<style id="21" fore-color="#F77B09" back-color="#F0F0F0" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_HIDDENCOMMAND -->

<style id="3" fore-color="#A58E37" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_VARIABLE -->
<style id="4" fore-color="#A58E37" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SYSTEMVARIABLE -->
<style id="5" fore-color="#A58E37" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KNOWNSYSTEMVARIABLE -->

<style id="6" fore-color="#F0A030" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_NUMBER -->
<style id="12" fore-color="#209F20" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SQSTRING -->
<style id="13" fore-color="#6D4A27" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DQSTRING -->

<style id="7" fore-color="#007FBF" bold="Yes" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_MAJORKEYWORD -->
<style id="8" fore-color="#007FBF" bold="Yes"/> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KEYWORD -->
<style id="15" fore-color="#C040C0" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_FUNCTION -->
<style id="10" fore-color="#C04000" bold="Yes" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PROCEDUREKEYWORD -->
<style id="14" bold="Yes" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_OPERATOR -->

<style id="16" fore-color="#000000" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_IDENTIFIER -->
<style id="17" fore-color="#7D5A27" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_QUOTEDIDENTIFIER -->

<style id="22" fore-color="#FFFFFF" back-color="#A0A0A0" bold="Yes" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PLACEHOLDER -->

<style id="18" fore-color="#007F00" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER1 -->

<!-- All styles again in their variant in a hidden command (with a 0x40 offset). -->
<style id="65" fore-color="#A0A0A0" back-color="#F0F0F0" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENT -->
<style id="66" fore-color="#A0A0A0" back-color="#F0F0F0" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENTLINE -->
```

/usr/share/mysql-workbench/data/code_editor.xml

in Ubuntu it will available on following location (default)
else try to find with locate command and other os find in installation directory

after editing this xml restart the workbench

Comment: try to change     <style id="1" fore-color="#A0A0A0" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENT -->
<style id="2" fore-color="#A0A0A0" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENTLINE -->